# WPF app not debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a WPF app in VS2013ExpressForWD and whenever I try to debug this specific app, an exception gets thrown.
This is my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="GlobalTimeElite.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="GlobalTimeElite"
        MinHeight="500" MinWidth="700">
  <Grid>
    <!-- Heading -->
    <Button x:Name="HelpPage" Content="Help"
            HorizontalAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="20" Height="25"
            FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14"
            Click="SwitchToHelpPage">
    </Button>
    <Label x:Name="Heading" Content="GlobalTimeElite"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Margin="0,60,0,0"
           FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="48">
    </Label>
    <Label x:Name="SubHeading" Content="WPF Edition"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Margin="0,100,0,0"
           FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14">
    </Label>

    <!-- Desc -->
    <Label x:Name="Description" Content="CodeBehind shalt tell thee, XAML!"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Margin="20,160,0,0"
           FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="19.5">
    </Label>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GlobalTimeElite
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Description.Content = "Choose one of the options you see below this text.\n"
                                + "For help about these, double click this text or clic"
                                + "k the \"HELP\" \nbutton on the upper-left corner of "
                                + "this Window.";

        }

        internal void SwitchToHelpPage(Object Sender, EventArgs Event)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error message when I debug:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '8' and line position '35'.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued
```

Answer (score 1):

The First Button in your grid (`x:Name="HelpPage"`) has invalid `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`. Maybe you swapped them?

Legal values for HorizontalAlignment are: `Center`, `Left`, `Right` and `Stretch`.

Legal values for VerticalAlignmentare: `Center`, `Bottom`, `Top` and `Stretch`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explore `XamlParseException`. Just look at `InnerException`:

[image]

Here's the problem line:

```
<Button x:Name="HelpPage" Content="Help"
    HorizontalAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Left"
```

You've mixed up enum values. The right way:

```
<Button x:Name="HelpPage" Content="Help"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
```